# Models of arithmetic in a signature with exponentiation but not addition and multiplication

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, theories-of-arithmetic

Let $\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{exp}}$ be the language with signature $(0, ^\prime, <, \mathrm{exp})$ (with $0$ interpreted as zero, $^\prime$ as successor, and $\mathrm{exp}(x)$ as $2^x$) and let $\mathsf{TA}_{\mathrm{exp}}$ be true arithmetic in this signature; i.e. $\{ \phi \in \mathsf{Sent}(\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{exp}}): \mathbb{N} \vDash \phi \}$.

What is known about the models of $\mathsf{TA}_{\mathrm{exp}}$? Does the analogue of Tennenbaum's theorem hold? I've loooked around a bit, but haven't been able to find anything; pointers to the literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Obvious* means: $'$ is successor $x'=x+1$ and $\text{exp}(x)=2^x$?

Comment: If exp were a binary function, $\exp(x,y)=x^y$, then you could define multiplication because $yz=w$ iff $\forall x(\exp(\exp(x,y),z))=\exp(x,w))$. Then you could define addition because $y+z=w$ iff $\forall x(\exp(x,y)\exp(x,z)=\exp(x,w))$. I therefore agree with @JoelDavidHamkins that exp had better be unary with a fixed base, presumably $2$.

Comment: (Note that $0$ and $'$ are definable from $<$.) Conjecture: the theory is completely axiomatized by  axioms of discrete linear order with least element, $x<y\to\exp(x)<\exp(y)$, $\exp(0^{(k)})=0^{(2^k)}$ and $0^{(k)}<x\to x^{(k)}<\exp(x)$ for all standard $k\in\mathbb N$. If true, this would imply the theory has plenty of recursive nonstandard models.

Comment: Sorry, one more schema: $0^{(k)}<x<y\to\exp(x)^{(k)}<\exp(y)$.

Comment: Ok, I think I can prove it, and also that the theory has quantifier elimination in a language with predecessor and $\lfloor\log x\rfloor$. However, I can neither check it in more detail nor type it up until I'm back in office next week.

Comment: I recall there is some literature on Presburger arithmetic with exponentiation. I don't know what the results are, but it could also answer the question.

Comment: Joel: Sorry, yes I was thinking of $\mathrm{exp}$ as $2^x$.

Comment: @beau In that case, I'd recommend editing your question for clarity. In my experience, notation or terminology that is familiar to or even standard with one mathematician, such as using the prime symbol $'$ for successor, can be totally unfamiliar in other mathematical communities, even very strong ones. Here on MathOverflow, where we communicate with a truly diverse crowd, it is best to explain one's meaning well.

Comment: Joel: Thanks for the suggestion! Edited.

Answer (score 7):

$\mathsf{TA}_{\exp}$ does have recursive nonstandard models. In fact, even the considerably stronger theory $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb N,+,2^x)$ (Presburger arithmetic with exponentiation) has recursive nonstandard models. This follows from results of Semënov, elaborated in [this paper](http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/%7Epoint/papiers/Pres.pdf) by Point: the theory is decidable (with an explicitly given axiom set), and it has elimination of quantifiers in a language expanded with $<$, congruence predicates, and the logarithm function $\ell(x)=\lfloor\log_2(x)\rfloor$.

It is a general fact that any decidable theory has a recursive model, and even a model with decidable satisfaction predicate. Now here we have the minor problem that this construction may happen to produce the standard recursive model; thus, we apply it to the theory expanded with a new constant $c$, along with axioms making $c$ nonstandard. We need to make sure the theory is still decidable, and one way to do that is to use the quantifier elimination result to exhibit a recursively axiomatized complete type. I didn’t check this in detail, but I believe it is possible.

Alternatively, one may do something similar directly for the theory of $\mathsf{TA}_{\exp}=\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb N,<,2^x)$. I did verify the details, but unfortunately, the full proof is too long to present here, so I will only state the results with a few hints.

> **Theorem:**
>
> 1. $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb N,0,{}',<,2^x)$ is decidable, and it can be explicitly axiomatized by
>
>    a. the axioms of a discrete linear order with a least element and no largest element;
>
>    b. the axioms $x<\exp(x)$, $x<y\to\exp(x)<\exp(y)$, and $\forall x>0\,\exists y\,(\exp(y)\le x<\exp(y'))$;
>
>    c. the axioms $\exp(\overline k)=\overline{2^k}$ and $\overline k<x\to\exp(x)+k<\exp(x')$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$, where $x+0:=x$, $x+(k+1):=(x+k)'$, and $\overline k:=0+k$.
> 2. The theory has quantifier elimination in the language $L_\ell=(0,{}',x\mathbin{\dot{\smash-}}1,<,\ell)$ (note: $\exp$ not needed).
> 3. Every formula in one variable is equivalent to a Boolean combination of formulas of the form $x=\overline k$ and $P(\ell(\dots(\ell(x))\dots)+k)$ (possibly with negative $k$, defined in the obvious way), where $P(x)$ denotes $x=\exp(\ell(x))$ (i.e., “$x$ is a power of $2$”).

The proof is syntactic: one first proves that any quantifier-free formula of $L_{\ell,\exp}:=L_\ell\cup\{\exp\}$ is equivalent to a quantifier-free formula of $L_\ell$ of a suitable form, and that such a quantifier-free formula in one variable is equivalent to one of the form 3. Using this, we show that any $L_{\ell,\exp}$-formula with one quantifier is equivalent to a quantifier-free formula.

We can then produce a recursive nonstandard model by the general result above. In particular, the quantifier elimination result implies that the theory expanded with a new constant $c$ with the sequence of axioms $P(\ell(\dots(\ell(c))\dots))$ is complete, hence decidable, hence it has a recursive model.

Note that the theory is universally axiomatizable in $L_{\ell,\exp}$, hence any $L_{\ell,\exp}$-submodel of a model of the theory is elementary. Thus, we may take the model generated by $c$, which can be explicitly described by giving a normal form for terms in one variable, and I believe it is equivalent to the model given in Matt F.’s current answer.

Answer (score 1):

*A third try, with thanks to Emil Jerabek for correcting the previous two:*

The following $\mathcal{M}=(S,0,',<,\exp)$ is a recursive non-standard model for the language, and I conjecture that it is a model for the theory:

The sequence $(a,b,c;k)$ is intended to represent
\begin{align}
&a + \exp(b+\exp(c+\omega) &\text{ if }k=0 \\
&a + \exp(b+\exp(c+\exp\cdots\exp\omega) &\text{ if }k>0 \\
&a + \exp(b+\exp(c+\log\cdots\log\omega) &\text{ if }k<0
\end{align}
with $|k|$ operations of $\exp$ or $\log$ on a non-standard $\omega$.

Formally, let $S$ be the union of $\mathbf{N}$ and
$$\{(z_1,\ldots,z_n;k)\}\ /\ ((z_1,\ldots,z_n;k) \sim (z_1,\ldots,z_n,0;k-1))$$
where $z_i,n,k\in \mathbf{Z}$ and $n>1$.  Note that $n+k$ is well-defined, and given any sequence, we can choose a representative of its equivalence class which has arbitrarily high $n$ and low $k$.

Let the $0$ for $S$ be the usual $0$ in $\mathbf{N}$.  Let $'$ and $\exp$ be defined in the standard way on $\mathbf{N}$, and by
$$(z_1,\ldots,z_n;k)'=(z_1+1,z_2,\ldots,z_n;k),$$
$$\exp(z_1,\ldots,z_n;k)=(0,z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n;k).$$

Let $<$ be defined such that $\mathbf{N}$ is less than all the sequences, with the standard order on $\mathbf{N}$ and $x<x'$ iff $x$ and $x'$ have representatives 
$$x = (z_1,\ldots,z_n;k),\,\ x'=(z'_1,\ldots,z'_{n'};k')$$
with either $n+k <n'+k'$, or $n=n'$, $k=k'$ and $z_j<z'_j$ for the last $j$ where $z$ and $z'$ differ.

Now define $\lfloor \log(x) \rfloor$ for $x=(z_1,\ldots,z_n;k)$, $n \ge 3$, by
$$y=
\begin{cases}
(\phantom{-1+}z_2,z_3,\ldots,z_n;k) \text{ if } \ z_1 \ge 0\\
(-1+z_2,z_3,\ldots,z_n;k) \text{ if } \ z_1 < 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
and this satisfies $\exp(y) \le x < \exp(y')$.

I'm interested in any suggestions of sentences in $Th(\mathbf{N},0,',<,\exp)$ which might not be true in $\mathcal{M}$.